# How to set variables via eval() when JS compressors rename variables?

Tags: javascript, compression

I have a JS file that does something like this:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem(somekey);
if ( !value )
{
  eval("value = String(" + somevariablename + ");");
}
```

This script tries to retrieve a value from Local Storage. If the value does not exist in Local Storage, it sets to using an eval off of the value of a previously defined variable. The eval is necessary for me in this case since the value of `value` has to be set to the String value of a variable name. I don't know any other way around this.

The problem is that most good JS Compressors offer a way to automatically rename variable names in order to save space. I end up with something like this:

```
var f=localStorage.getItem(e);
if(!f){eval("value = String("+e+");")}
```

So the problem is that my variable got renamed but the compressor doesn't know to change the name of the variable in the eval string. I have never seen a compressor that was smart enough to figure that out.

What is the best way to deal with this in an automated fashion in a build environment? Going in and manually changing the variable name in the evals is pretty time consuming since in my case, code like this occurs a lot.

Comment: Why use eval? Just use `value = somevariablename.toString()`

Comment: You could use eval like that: `value = eval("String(" + somevariablename + ")")` - the question is: if the variable names change, how do you now that the variable name in `somevariablename` is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use eval to create variable on the fly.

You can simply catch the global object, and then any property created on it is a variable on the global scope anyway...

window["value"] = "something";

And then by creating your variable this way, you do not have to use eval to get the variable names since you are creating them with a string.